# Content field in new entries do not write to the database

Tags: database, entry

I have been experiencing an issue in our UAT environment in regards to new entries. When I publish a new entry, the entry id and the title get written to the database, but the text in the Wygwam field does not. I have to go back into the entry again and paste the content into the Wygwam field and then it will write to the database. Has anyone ever experienced this before? Does anyone have any idea what the culprit could be?

Comment: My first guess would be character encoding issues. Have you got all of your encoding prefs set to UTF8?

Comment: Does this only occur with Wygwam fields? What about EE textarea fields? Only in this channel, or in all channels? These would be good first steps in debugging.

Comment: Yes, Character encoding set to utf-8 and this occurs in all fields, not just Wygwam.

Comment: What about disabling extensions? Perhaps an extension is inadvertently blanking out the data destined for `exp_channel_data` when publishing a new entry.

Comment: The strange thing is that this is only happening in a UAT environment. The exact same installation is running perfectly in 4 other environments. I am thinking it must have something to do with the way the database or server is set up in this UAT environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the first thing I do when running into an issue with something I have used for a long time which has worked well is to simplify the environment. In this case I would create a test channel with only a Wygwam field (use a preset config rather than a custom config.) If this works then perhaps Wygwam (or more specifically, the JS) is conflicting with another field.